# Docker & gcplogs : message as json

Tags: docker, logging, google-cloud-platform

I run a project deployed with `docker-compose` using `gcplogs` driver. I wonder if it's possible to transform a message string written in `stdout` to a complex JSON payload.

Actually I have to use the following specific log format to retrieve logs in stackdriver, so the payload look like this in Stackdriver:

```json
{
  "container": {…}   
  "instance": {…}   
  "message":  "service:php type:NOTICE message:\"The message I want to log\""   
 }
```

I've tried to format the message as JSON but ends up with the message property containing the stringified JSON:

```json
{
  "container": {…}   
  "instance": {…}   
  "message":  "{\"service\":\"php\",\"type\":\"NOTICE\",\"message\":\"The message I want to log\"}"
 }
```

Is there any config in `docker-compose` to automatically parse the message string as the JSON payload? Like the option `--payload-type=json` when using gcloud with CLI? Maybe its possible with `fluentd` driver but is it correctly handled by gcp ?

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the **Google's** version of **fluentd** which already comes preconfigured to work with Stackdriver (e.g. it auto-discovers the credentials when running from inside a GCP VM).

1. [Install google-fluentd](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation) directly on your VM (outside of Docker)

   ```
   $ curl -sSO https://dl.google.com/cloudagents/install-logging-agent.sh
   $ sudo bash install-logging-agent.sh
   ```
2. You can remove all the default boilerplate configuration from fluentd config file (`etc/google-fluentd/google-fluentd.conf` on Ubuntu) and just add the configuration for your particular service (providing you don't need to use google-fluentd for anything else). In order to do so remove everything **before** the section starting with `<match **>` and insert the following configuration instead:

   ```
   <source>
     @type forward
     port 24225
     bind 127.0.0.1
   </source>

   <filter **>
     @type add_insert_ids
   </filter>

   <filter **>
     @type parser
     key_name message
     <parse>
       @type json
     </parse>
   </filter>
   ```
3. Reload fluentd:

   `$ sudo systemctl reload google-fluentd`
4. Set fluentd as a **logging driver** with destination `localhost:24225` for your app container, or simply change the **default logging driver** for the whole Docker Engine in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

   ```
   {
     "log-driver": "fluentd",
     "log-opts": {
       "fluentd-address": "localhost:24225"
     }
   }
   ```

   and reload Docker:

   `$ sudo systemctl reload docker`

From now on you should see your application logs nicely parsed out in the Stackdriver Logging viewer. If you don't, check the fluentd log (`/var/log/google-fluentd/google-fluentd.log` on Ubuntu) for possible issues with JSON parsing.

Comment: Filter section with `add_insert_ids` should go after section with `parser`, overwise `insertId` will be missing in the final entry.

Comment: Also ensure that you have valid timestamp in the final message (you can find it out with `stdout` test output). My logs has time field like `"time":"2021-01-14T21:37:48.851974177Z"` inside JSON log entry, so I had to add the following to the `<parse>`: `time_type string` and `time_format %FT%T.%N%z`

Before that my messages were silently ignored by google cloud.